# Mostrar datos dinámicamente sin refrescar la página

Tags: javascript, php

En mi página tengo imágenes de miniaturas de los productos.

#### Mecanismo:

1. Al hacer click en un producto, envía los datos del producto como parámetros GET.
2. Los recibo en el script PHP y, evaluando en cuál se hizo click, muestro la descripción del producto.
3. Si luego el usuario quiere ver otro producto, vuelvo al punto (1).

#### Problema:

Es poco práctico que esté recargando toda la página cada vez que se quiere ver la descripción de un producto.

#### Código

Cada miniatura es un link, como por ejemplo:

```
www.tienda.com.ar/productos.php?producto=calesita&art=115
                                         ^^^^^^^^     ^^^
```

**PHP**

```php
<a href="productos.php?producto=calesita&art=115>ART 115</a>
<a href="productos.php?producto=calesita&art=116>ART 116</a>
<a href="productos.php?producto=calesita&art=117>ART 117</a>

if($_GET['producto'] == "calesita") {

    switch($_GET['producto]) {
        case 115:
            $arti = array("115", "modelo1");
            break;
        case 116:
            $arti = array("116", "modelo2");
            break;
        case 117:
            $arti = array("117", "modelo3");
            break;
    }

    echo "Numero: " . $arti[0];
    echo "Modelo: " . $arti[1];
}
```

#### Pregunta

Quiero hacer esto mismo en JavaScript para que cargue todo del lado del cliente y sea mas sencilla.

¿Cómo se puede hacer que al clickear cambien los datos igual que en PHP pero sin refrescar la página?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44207/discussion-on-question-by-nicolas-paolillo-mostrar-datos-dinamicamente-sin-refre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo deje en PHP y lo solucione con AJAX:

Pase los valores por GET y los mostre con PHP.

```js
function pasarVal(produ, arti) {
    $.get("productos.php", {
        producto: produ,
        art: arti
    }, function(htmlexterno) {
        $("#productos").html(htmlexterno);
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar lo que tu deseas (solo refrescar porciones de una página web) se utiliza AJAX.

AJAX, acrónimo de Asynchronous JavaScript And XML (JavaScript asíncrono y XML), es una técnica de desarrollo web para crear aplicaciones interactivas o RIA (Rich Internet Applications). [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

Para utilizar esta técnica, lo puedes hacer de diferentes formas. 
La libreria mas común en el ambito de JavaScript, es jQuery.

Por medio de esta libreria, puede realizar peticiones AJAX facilmente.

Un ejemplo tomado de "w3schools":

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```